# Web 8.5 XPM created page based on page template but show "page not found"

Tags: web8.5, experience-manager

Currently testing the XPM function in stating environment(Using DXA 1.6 version ), while creating a new page in the beginning the status shows "creating page", then after a while, it goes to "page not found". But if I stay in the same page and click "Update preview", the new page will come out. see attached screenshot.

I think the created page needs to be published, then it can show up. but why it shows "page not found" 404 error, but after clicked "Update preview" button, the page can be shown correctly?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange @Brain: Try in the fiddler or chrome developer tools to see which path or page URL trying to access and getting the 404 error. Is there any error in your web app or preview service?

Answer (score 1):

There is a moment between requesting a new page and having it rendered where it actually does not exist (i.e. a legitimate 404).

However, Experience Manager can handle this moment through a configured "blank" page, delivered through the root folder of your Staging site.

See the [Documentation for instructions](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-A484302D-31DA-474E-B70F-3A98773C38F7) for creating a blank `se_blank.html` to avoid such 404s. This is handled by default by DXA's `PageController.Blank` (thanks, Rick!).

**Update**: Updated the answer to include DXA's built-in route to handle this blank page.

Comment: DXA has a built-in route for this (handled by `PageController.Blank`, which returns empty content.)

Comment: Thanks all for your reply. if I setup this "blank" page, when user created a page in XPM, then they will see this setup blank page, but they have to click "update preview" button to see the created page, right?  anyway, they need to click this "update preview" button ?

Comment: From memory, I believe when XPM is _publishing_ a page it will both prompt the user there was a change and attempt to refresh the browser. Perhaps wait or investigate to see if this also happens for new pages but I'm pretty sure the user should eventually see a page without needing to click update preview.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, I just installed web8.5 + DXA1.6 and test it again. I created page in XMP, it show -> creating page -> loading -> page not found status -> click "update preview", page shown up. I also setup se_blank.html, but still see like this. (see attached)    But in my testing evvironment Tridion 9.1 + DXA2.2 it works without issue.  I think this probably is a bug for XPM.

Comment: Yeah, it could be specific to XPM in 8.5 or DXA 1.6. Consider working with Support and/or seeing if you can narrow down the issue.

For the screenshot and additional details, feel free to add to your original post with clarification or some updates to help others either answer or find this post in the future.

And thanks for asking!